# How can i build a compound index based on embedded document fields with Mongoose

Tags: mongoose

as the title says, i'm trying to make a compound index on mongoose based on a subdocument fields, this is what my schema look like.

```js
pricingSchema = new Schema({
 retail:{ //normal retail price
  type:Number
 },
 retailOnDiscount:{ //retail during solde
  type:Number
 },
 savings:{ //price which will be saved by the customer
  type:Number
 },
 pct_savings:{ //saving percentage
  type:Number
 }
});

ar ProductSchema = new Schema({                                                                                                                                                                                    
    sku: {                                                                                                                                                                                                            
     type: Number                                                                                                                                                                                                    
   },                                                                                                                                                                                              
   kind: {                                                                                                                                                                                                           
     type: String                                                                                                                                                                                                    
   },                                                                                                                                                                                                                
   title: {                                                                                                                                                                                                          
     type: String                                                                                                                                                                                                    
   },                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
   shipping:shippingSchema,
   pricing:pricingSchema,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
   details:detailSchema,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   description: {                                                                                                                                                                                                    
     type: String                                                                                                                                                                                                    
   },                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
   imageUrl: {                                                                                                                                                                                                         
     type: Array                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
});
```

I have tried the command below

```js
ProductSchema.index({pricing.pct_savings:1,type:-1});
```

But i get this error:

```js
/Users/willy/workspace/dev/le-beau-cheveu/dev/backend-v2/server/api/product/productModel.js:111
ProductSchema.index({pricing.pct_savings:1,type:-1});//compound index at the schema level
                            ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/willy/workspace/dev/le-beau-cheveu/dev/backend-v2/server/api/product/productController.js:1:77)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/willy/workspace/dev/le-beau-cheveu/dev/backend-v2/server/api/product/productRoutes.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
```

Can anyone help me, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its just the wrong JSON property syntax, you need the key to be defined as a string. `.` is not accepted in key name unless the key is defined using quotes

```
ProductSchema.index({'pricing.pct_savings':1,type:-1});
```